# "Know jack" vs. "Don't know jack."

Tags: slang, negative-polarity-items, vernacular

When you want to say that someone doesn't know anything about a particular thing, do you say they don't know jack about it, or that they know jack about it?

I've seen it used both ways. Which is correct?

Comment: See *Flaubert triggers, squatitive negation, and other quirks of grammar* (Laurence R. Horn 2001)

Comment: Related: [The meaning of a phrase that has one of four-letter words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/379362)

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20437/origin-of-jack-sht

Comment: "Jack" is a redacted version of "jack shit".

Comment: This particular one is on the [list of ***Squatitives***](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/152488/15299) produced by Haj Ross and Paul Postal.

Answer (score 1):

That this and similar slang expressions set up the apparent paradox of *x = not x* has a [particular fascination](http://www.academia.edu/3147486/Squat_zero_and_no_nothing_Syntactic_negation_vs._Semantic_negation_UGent_GIST) for [linguists](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Laurence_Horn/publication/285102407_Flaubert_triggers_squatitive_negation_and_other_quirks_of_grammar/links/57d4457508ae6399a3922209/Flaubert-triggers-squatitive-negation-and-other-quirks-of-grammar.pdf). The logic, however, is easy to grasp.

If *jack* is a quantity of absolutely no value, i. e. zero, then the difference between

> He knows zero.

and

> He doesn't know zero.

is basically zero.

Both expressions are "correct" in the descriptive sense that native speakers use both.